# Adding Percentage on Stacked Visual

Tags: powerbi

How do I have the percent of the category show up on the stacked visual without removing the totals?

I tried using the line and stacked column chart; however the percentage is always 100% and doesn't breakdown by category.

I want to get the 16.15% to be labelled on the orange area while keeping the "Sum of Amounts (lbs)" y-axis and values.

[image: My current Graph]